# Info about managment compansation schemes in publicly traded companies

Tags: stock-valuation, compensation, board-of-directors

How or where could I find info about publicly traded companies about how stock owner friendly their compensation schemes are for their board and officers?

I would like this info as a part of my decision-making process of investing in stocks.

Background: Nowadays board and officers seem to secretly steal money from shareholders through options and other ways. The stock buybacks that people think should boost the earnings per stock is in reality issued back to the management of the company and is a more stealth way to take money from the company compared to take higher salaries.

Comment: This should be available in the annual report, probably in a directors' remunerations section for most companies. Are you able to provide any evidence of anything you allege in your "background" section? If the board and officers of a company are stealing money from shareholders that is a matter for law enforcement or at least the courts and director remunerations are voted on at AGMs.

Comment: Are you sure it is stealing and not just disclosed in big documents that people may be too lazy to read through to understand the compensation given to employees?

Comment: Fraudulent behavior and stealing is obviously the same thing for anyone with a sound mind. I hoped that would be what was to be found in here. Maybe I was wrong.

Comment: Fortunately many analytics today have a watch for these kinds of schemes to see that the management takes a fair share and that it is transparent. AFAIK it isn't decided on annual meetings to whom all options given out as remunerations should go to.

Comment: For US, _past_ year comp is in 10K, as (now) answered. However proposed _next_ year comp in the proxy solicitation (14A and often addenda thereto) is IME usually explained in much more detail. Other countries probably differ, although a few UK holdings I've had over the years were similar to US practice.

Answer (score 3):

Compensation information is available in the annual reports (10-k filings) which are available from the SEC EDGAR system or, generally, the company's website.  Additionally, insider transactions are reported to the SEC so you can see when an insider buys or sells stock or exercises options received as compensation.

> Background: Nowadays board and officers seem to secretly steal money from shareholders through options and other ways. The stock buybacks that people think should boost the earnings per stock is in reality issued back to the management of the company and is a more stealth way to take money from the company compared to take higher salaries.

... How do you know this is happening if you don't know where to go to get the data needed to determine whether or not this is happening?  Do you really think company share buybacks involve just the amount of shares to pay an executive?  Apple has bought back $117,000,000,000 worth of shares from the fourth quarter 2012 through the second quarter 2016, and paid a pretty substantial amount in dividends over the same period.  Do you really think these shares were simply handed to the executives?  The huge pension funds and other huge investors would not let this slide for very long if it were even close to being true.

Don't come to an unfounded conclusion then seek data to prove your position.  Look at and analyze data THEN come to a conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

Converting the comment from @MD-Tech into answer

> How or where could I find info about publicly traded companies about how stock owner friendly their compensation schemes are for their board and officers?

This should be available in the annual report, probably in a directors' remunerations section for most companies